# java socket equals method

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Say I have a server connected to many clients. When one client sends a packet to the server, the server will forward the packet to all other clients except the one where it sent from. The server keeps a list of neighboring clients' socket (ie. ArrayList of Socket object) and the socket that server accepted and assigned is called clientSocket. I want to go through the arraylist and compare each of socket with clientSocket to make sure the packet will not forward to original client. Can I simply use clientSocket.equals(neighborSocket) to check? Or I have to extract IP address and compare based on that? I'm using java socket. Thanks!

Comment: You could add the code where you create your objects and where you check for equality. I would check the documentation on that class to see if the method does what you need. Probably it inherits the method from the `Object` class, in which case it's just equivalent to using the `==` operator, and which is good enough if they are the same objects.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you mean `! clientSocket.equals(neighborSocket)`. Assuming that is the case, I think you can (and should) use `clientSocket != neighborSocket`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't care if the sockets are logically equal in some way. You care if they are identical. Therefore you should use ==.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an Old thread , adding my 2 cents if anybody reaches here by google java.net.Socket implementation inherits equals from Object, Below is equals implementation from Object

```
     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         return (this == obj);
     }
```

Hence in case of Socket  equals = (==).